# Windows 2012 remote access can't connect

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, rdp, service, vnc

I have installed Windows Server 2012 for about 9 months ago. Earlier I could connect to my server with an external IP perfectly, but the license for the remote desktop services has ended.

First, I thought it was the reason, why I couldn't use my server as RDP-server, to which users may connect.

But, than in web I read, that it's possible to use windows native features, just to remove the RDP services, which are trial and the server will work as RDP-server, but with some limitations ( for e.g. such free RDP service may accept only 1 connection and other connection will be disconnected etc ).

Is it true, that it's possible? If yes, please give a piece of advice, how should I repair it.

Because I don't want to use TightVNC or other stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Repair it? It's not broken, just buy the required license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a licensing issue. If you use Remote Desktop solely for the purpose of remote administration, you can uninstall the RDP role - it is not needed. Server will allow up to 2 simultaneous connections.

If Remote Desktop is used for remote work (non-administrative users are accessing the server to run their applications), you need to buy Remote Desktop Client Access Licenses either for each user or for each device that is accessing the server in this way.

For details see this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725933.aspx).