# Windows 2012 Remote Desktop License error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, licensing, remote-desktop-services

I am exactly in this situation:

[Windows 2012 remote access can't connect](https://serverfault.com/questions/518656/windows-2012-remote-access-cant-connect)

The RDS role was installed erroneously, and the grace period to decide the licensing mode was left to expire; when I tried to connect, I was greeted with (the Italian localized version of) this message:

[image: Remote Desktop Connection - The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a licence. Please contact the server administrator.]

Since we use RDP just for remote administration, after reading around that [two administrative connections are "built in" if the RDS role is not installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/444970/remote-desktop-licensing-mode-is-not-configured-in-windows-server2012), I removed the RDS role and rebooted; as a result, it was impossible to connect - the 3389 port wasn't even open.

Then, I found that the Remote Desktop setting in the System properties dialog (the same that you would use to enable RDP on a non-server machine) wasn't enabled; I enabled it, and now when connecting I get this message:

[image: Errore licenza - Prego contattare l'amministratore]

(in English that would be "License error - Please contact the administrator")

which *is* in fact different from what appeared before (when the RDS role was enabled), but it still isn't letting me in. I restarted the various RDP-related services to no avail.

This appears exactly the same both when connecting with `mstsc` from a Windows machine (with and without `/admin`) and `rdesktop` from a Linux machine (with and without `-0`, which AFAIK now shouldn't even have an effect on Windows >2008 Server).

<s>Is this going to go away after yet another reboot or I have to perform some other magic to convince this thing to let me in?</s> No, rebooting didn't fix anything. Suggestions?

Comment: have you checked rdp is enabled in server ? just like a normal pc ? and also i feel you have not removed all the  RDS roles and restarted ?

Comment: in run (Windows+R) try tsadmin.msc  and see you see session host server available

Comment: @Aravinda: [RDP is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z39aP.png); [tsadmin.msc doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyUf4.png); all the roles about RDS I could find have been removed.

Comment: Here are few suggestions at this point .. see https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/40598-fix-remote-session-was-disconnected-because-there-are-no-remote-desktop-client-access-licenses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extra reboot/update install the problem fixed itself. No idea what may have fixed it, let's hope it keeps working.